# Images in server component loading first . before Carousel client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[It coming like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXV2q.png)

My problem..
I am building an application using next js.
I am getting like this what to do ?
I am fetching the data image in server component and i am using client caraousel component .
i want to display my image in carousel only after client component got rendered ?
How to load the images in the carousel after client component renders.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.